# Ruby on Rails - Road Error 「Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'」

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

http://railstutorial.jp/ に取り組んでいます。
RailsInstallerのRuby2.1をインストールし、その後はページに記載されている通りに操作を行ってきました。
1.2.5において、rails serverコマンドを実行し、ローカルWebサーバを起動させようとしたところ、いくつかのエラーが出たため、ブログサイト等を利用して解決しました。解決した問題は、WindowsにおけるRails環境特有のものと書かれていました。例えば、‘x64_mingw’ is not a valid platform などです。しかし、今直面しているエラーは以下の様なもので、検索しても望ましい情報を得ることができませんでした。

> Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter'.
>   Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use
>   an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add
>   the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.

Gemfileは以下の様になっています。前述の通り、チュートリアルで指示されたとおりに編集した後、rails serverコマンドによって遭遇した問題を解決するために、何度か編集を加えました。

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```

このエラーの原因と解決策をご教示ください。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371809/rails-sqlite-adapter-error][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7371809/rails-sqlite-adapter-error


海外のスタックオーバーフローではこんな感じですね。

Answer (score 1):

Railsチュートリアルで使われているRailsのバージョンは4.0.5、Rubyのバージョンは2.0.0だったと思います。RubyとRailsのバージョンをRailsチュートリアルで使われているものに合わせて再度試して見るとよいのではないでしょうか。

動作確認済みのバージョン番号を指定したGemfileは以下のようです。
http://railstutorial.jp/chapters/beginning?version=4.0#sec-install_rails

```ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.5'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.5'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end
```